# convert new Date().getTimezoneOffset() to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'll need to convert JS function below to exact function in PHP.

```
var user_timezone_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60;
```

This is my PHP code, but $user_timezone_offset returns different value than JS:

```
$TZ = 'America/Chicago';
$user_localtime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($TZ));
$user_timezone_offset = $user_localtime->getOffset();
```

**The returned values must be exact same in both cases. Now is one 3600 (from PHP) and second value is negative -3600 (from JS)**

Comment: what does `new Date` displays in the javascript console?

Answer (score 2):

`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` gives you the offset in minutes, so just multiply that by 60 to get the offset in seconds, which is what PHP uses.

```
var user_timezone_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
```

Comment: This return same value but not exact same value. In my timezone, PHP func. return 3600 and javascript -3600 (= negative). I'll need to return exact same value (positive/negative value). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These two languages using different positions when calculating the difference like utc - tz or tz - utc. You need to multiply by "-60" in javascript side.

```js
var user_timezone_offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * -60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my conversion code. PHP actually using diferrent positions of +/-

```
// ....
private function convertOffset(string $offset): string
{
    $sign = substr($offset, 0, 1) === '+' ? '-' : '+'; // switch sign
    $minutes = (int)substr($offset, 1); // get int minutes
    $hours = floor($minutes / 60); // whole hours
    $restMinutes = $minutes - ($hours * 60);
    return $sign
        .str_pad((string)$hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
        .str_pad((string)$restMinutes, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)
        ;
}
```